# Libreoffice Calc, print barcodes font, stretch font taller but not wider

Tags: fonts, libreoffice, barcode-scanner

I'm using Libreoffice Calc to print stock labels. I've encoded the texts for use with the code128 format, same as in this [online tool](https://www.bcgen.com/fontencoder/), and I can print the barcodes using the [Libre Barcode 128](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Libre+Barcode+128) font. When I print my normal size labels they scan correctly.

However I'm having trouble with small labels. The smaller labels need to be about 3,2cm wide in order to fit. So I set the font size to 16pt, but then they don't always scan as easily. Most of the time the barcode scanner doesn't pick it up at all, only sometimes it scans correctly, so this is not a workable solution.

I'm guessing it has to do with barcode being too small in height, so not tall enough. So I figured to just print the same barcode stacked on top of each other in order to make the barcode lines longer. But then have to fidget with the font and cell settings, in order to "merge" the stacked barcodes seamlessly. And, at least in the print preview, it is still not seamless because there are horizontal white lines between the cells.

[image]

**So my quesion is**,
is there a better way to make fonts appear taller but not wider?
Or is there another way to print barcodes with taller lines?
Or is there maybe a better barcode128 font to use?

Comment: Just for any future reference; using multiple cells to stack up barcodes to make them taller was also a workable solution. The barcode scanner picks it up correctly, so it's a huge improvement compared to before. The horizontal white lines are much less noticable when printing. Be sure to set Row Height to about 0,30cm and set Format Cells, Padding, Border all to 0.0mm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had same problem with barcodes in the mid 90's, no google or even much internet then so it all took a bit longer to sort out i recall! Barcode scanners would beep when I walked past them in a striped shirt but would not scan my barcodes.

You need to make a double height version of your font. This is quite straightforward nowadays. Use online font tool [Glyphr Studio](http://www.glyphrstudio.com/online) and upload your barcode128 font. Go to global settings in menu and in re-size all glyphs option, put 2200 in the height box and click resize button (assuming that the height is already 2200, this doubles it to 4400). Then in font settings, glyph proportions, enter 4400 in the ascent height box. While still in font settings, give the font a name, code128L for example. Then select export menu and click OTF format and save. Click on your downloaded font and install it.

Comment: Thanks, Glyphr Studio is exactly what I need for this. :)